# TortoiseSVN and TortoiseHg server : unsupported OPTIONS method

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tortoisehg

I'm not sure why I cannot connect to a repo server on the lan (or localhost)

I've got the server running, and I can connect to it via browser, but I get this error on the client:

`Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://192.168.1.10:8000' OPTIONS of 'http://192.168.1.10:8000': Error reading response headers: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`

and this error on the server:
`"OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 501 -

 code 501, message Unsupported method ('OPTIONS')`

and I can't find any information on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- TortoiseSVN is (obviously) client for **Subversion repositories**
- Embedded into TortoiseHG server enable http access to **Mercurial repositories**

While both SCMs can use the same access layer (http:// protocol), they, generally, "speak on different languages"

Resume: you **must** to use HG client in order to read HG repo